# Feeding numpy uint8 into tensorflow float32 placeholder

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, type-conversion, one-hot-encoding

I recently found a proof of concept implementation, which prepares features in a one-hot encoding using `numpy.zeros`:

```
data = np.zeros((len(raw_data), n_input, vocab_size),dtype=np.uint8)
```

As could be seen above, the single ones are typed as `np.uint8`.
After inspecting the model, I realized that the input placeholder of the tensorflow model is defined as `tf.float32`:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input, vocab_size], name="onehotin")
```

**My particular question:**
How does tensorflow deal with this "mismatch" of input types. Are those values `(0/1)` correctly interpreted or casted by tensorflow. If so, is this somewhere mentioned in the docs. After googling I could not found a answer. It should be mentioned that the model runs and values seems plausible. However, typing the input numpy features as `np.float32` would cause a significant amount of memory needed.

**Relevance:**
A running but falsely trained model would behave differently after adopting the input pipeline / rolling out a model into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow supports dtype conversion like that.

In operations, such as `x + 1`, the value `1` is going through [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) function that takes care of validation and conversion. The function is sometimes called manually under the hood, and when the `dtype` argument is set, the value automatically gets converted to this type.

When you feed the array into a placeholder like that:

```
session.run(..., feed_dict={x: data})
```

... the data is explicitly converted to a numpy array of the right type via `np.asarray` call. See the source code at [`python/client/session.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L1110). Note that this method **may reallocate the buffer** when the dtype is different and that's exactly what's happening in your case. So your memory optimization doesn't quite work as you expect: the temporary 32-bit `data` is allocated internally.

Comment: Okay, thank you, perfect answer. The implicit conversion probably hurts...